# Удаление знаков переноса с возвратом строки

Tags: bash, sed

при выгрузке случился баг и после `data3` добавился знак переноса строки `\n`
и все сьехало на две строки.  `data3` обрамлен `"` (двойные ковычки)
файл очень большой 1 мил строк и в ручную не вариант переделывать
подскажите как через `sed` убрать перенос строки для того чтобы сьехавший хвост вытянулся в одну строку
сейчас файл имеет такой вид

```
data1,data2,"data3
",data4
data1,data2,"data3
",data4
data1,data2,"data3
",data4
```

а должен быть таким

```
data1,data2,"data3",data4
data1,data2,"data3",data4
data1,data2,"data3",data4
```

заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
sed 'N;s/\n"/"/'
```

У меня вроде работает:

```
[VladD@Kenga] [00:59:25] [~]
{0,504}$> cat xx.txt
data1,data2,"data3
",data4
data1,data2,"data3
",data4
data1,data2,"data3
",data4

[VladD@Kenga] [00:59:32] [~]
{0,505}$> sed 'N;s/\n"/"/' xx.txt
data1,data2,"data3",data4
data1,data2,"data3",data4
data1,data2,"data3",data4
```

Для более сложных случаев (возможны «обыкновенные» строки) попробуйте так:

```
sed '/^",/{H;x;s/\n//;x;d}; x' | sed '1d'
```

Проверка:

```
[VladD@Kenga] [01:35:47] [~]
{0,539}$> cat xx.txt 
header
"data1",data2,"data3
",data4
intermediate data
data1,"data2
","data3
",data4
data1,data2,"data3
",data4


[VladD@Kenga] [01:35:52] [~]
{0,540}$> sed '/^",/{H;x;s/\n//;x;d}; x' xx.txt 

header
"data1",data2,"data3",data4
intermediate data
data1,"data2","data3",data4
data1,data2,"data3",data4

[VladD@Kenga] [01:35:57] [~]
{0,541}$> sed '/^",/{H;x;s/\n//;x;d}; x' xx.txt | sed '1d'
header
"data1",data2,"data3",data4
intermediate data
data1,"data2","data3",data4
data1,data2,"data3",data4
```

**Внимение**: последняя строка должна заканчиваться переводом строки, иначе она будет «проглочена»!

---

Объяснение: нам необходимо, когда мы видим строку, начинающуюся с кавычки, знать предыдущую строку, чтобы склеить их. Для этого мы «задерживаем» вывод строк, отправляя их в hold space вместо вывода, и выводя вместо этого предыдущую строку, лежащую там же (`x`).

Для случая, когда строка начинается с кавычки (`/^"/`) начинаем действовать. В hold space лежит предыдущая строка, пристыковываем к ней текущую (`H`), и обмениваем hold space с pattern space (`x`), чтобы можно было обработать текст. Удаляем `\n` (`s/\n//`), и отправляем назад строку в hold space, чтобы проанализировать и вывести её на следующем цикле. Обрубок строки, который получился в pattern space, удаляем, и завершаем эту итерацию (`d`).

Comment: последний вариант с обыкновенными строками сработал отлично, спасибо огромное

Comment: @bandsed: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD, здорово, и наверное решает задачу ТС (а в общем виде, как он ее сформулировал в вопросе (т.е. если бы в исходной строке было несколько `data3`) к сожалению -- нет).  А вот  мне всегда проще написать несколько строк на Си минут за пять, чем в очередной раз разбираться с sed-ом по образцам, например, [отсюда](http://ant0.ru/sed1line.html).

Comment: @avp: Спасибо! Кстати, по идее работает и с многочисленными разрывами в строке: http://pastebin.com/MP4JJHV2. `sed` интересен как упражнение в очень низкоуровневом программировании, но более высокоуровневые средства, конечно, намного эффективнее в использовании.

Comment: @VladD, ага, был неправ. Вы же смотрите на `"` в начале строки, а не на `"data3` в конце (я просто заклинился на словах \n после `data3` в вопросе). / Заодно положу ответ с простым sh файлом, который объединяет строки по найденному концу строки (как сформулировано в вопросе)

Comment: @avp: Угу, я подумал, что `data3` — это placeholder, поэтому смотрю просто на `"` в начале следующей строки. Это сработает неправильно, если _первый_ элемент строки был сам по себе в кавычках (тогда надо наверное `/^",/`).

Answer (score 1):

тут может попробуете команду `tr` ?

```
tr '\n\",' ",' < input_filename
```

`sed` хорошо, но советуют `tr`

версия для `sed`

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\",\n/\",/g' file
```

1. **:a** создание метки **'a'**
2. **N** добавить следующую строку в формат
3. **$!** если не конец строки переход в метку **'a'**
4. **s** substitute, **/\",n/** regex для кавычки-запятой-новой_строки, **/\",/** заменить с кавычки-запятой, **/g** замена глобальная (сколько раз есть, столько работай)

Answer (score 1):

если структура получившегося файла точно соответстует приведённому примеру (надо объдинить 1 и 2 строку, 3 и 4 и т.д.), то выражение можно упростить, примерно как в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431254/178576):

```
$ cat старый.файл | sed 'N;s/\n//' > новый.файл
```

объяснение: для всех нечётных строк будет:

- прочитана следующая строка в конец `pattern space`
- из `pattern space` будет удалён символ перевода строки `\n` между этими двумя строками

Answer (score 1):

Мне проще написать такое на sh (или Си).

Объединяем строки, если после заданного текста был вставлен `\n` :

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ cat ts.sh
#!/bin/sh

IFS=""
while read -r s1
do
    if echo $s1 | grep $1'$' >/dev/null ; then
        echo -n $s1
    else
        echo $s1
    fi
done 

avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ cat ttt
header
data1,data2,"data3
",data4
intermediate data
data1,"data2
","data3
",data4
data1,data2,"data3
",data4
data1,"data3
"  "data3
 "data3
"data4
tailer
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./ts.sh \"data3 < ttt
header
data1,data2,"data3",data4
intermediate data
data1,"data2
","data3",data4
data1,data2,"data3",data4
data1,"data3"  "data3 "data3"data4
tailer
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

`IFS=""` заставляет sh (или bash) не разбивать строку на слова, а ключ `-r` говорит read, что backslash это обычный символ (см. `man 1 read`).