# Парсинг многострочной ошибки из лога bash

Tags: grep

У меня следующий вопрос есть в качестве исходных данных файл со строками вида

```
Jun 18 2020 12:46:20 | ERR | XFW | Common:1 | 10 | ORA Error, ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 32759
Session ID: 2291 Serial number: 11145
 while executing "DELETE FROM ATSD_Price WHERE (  ( Table_ID = :1 ) AND ( Entry_ID = :2 ) )" with :1="Scenario157", :2=37879.
Jun 18 2020 12:47:08 | TXT | APP | SG:1 | 9166 | One minute timer - 12:47
Jun 18 2020 12:47:20 | ERR | REFM | Common:1 | 17 | Request is Failed
Jun 18 2020 12:48:07 | TXT | APP | SG:1 | 9166 | One minute timer - 12:48
```

из него необходимо выбрать только строки с тегом ERR.
Но иногда ошибка многострочная как первая из представленных, иногда однострочная как вторая.
И в 1 случае мне нужны все строки ошибки развернутые в 1 строку разделенную пробелами, а во 2 случае только эта строка. То есть я хочу в итоге получить следующее:

```
Jun 18 2020 12:46:20 | ERR | XFW | Common:1 | 10 | ORA Error, ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel Process ID: 32759 Session ID: 2291 Serial number: 11145  while executing "DELETE FROM ATSD_Price WHERE (  ( Table_ID = :1 ) AND ( Entry_ID = :2 ) )" with :1="Scenario157", :2=37879.
Jun 18 2020 12:47:20 | ERR | REFM | Common:1 | 17 | Request is Failed
```

я думал над grep -A 4 ERR file и после этого развернуть строки в 1 и обрезать по 2 дате в строке, но я не уверен в том, что многострочная ошибка уберется в 4 строки, их может быть больше.
Как это можно сделать? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Регулярками можно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Взяв за основу ответ на вот этот вопрос [Удаление знаков переноса с возвратом строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431250/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)

я получил следующий вариант решения:

```
sed '/^[A-Z][a-z][a-z] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/!{H;x;s/\n/ /;x;d}; x' file | grep ERR
```

единственное принципиальное отличие от исходного решения в добавлении !, что приводит к поиску строк не начинающихся на паттерн.